# Lift of a diffeomorphism of the Torus

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry, algebraic-topology

I'm trying to prove the following formula. Suppose to have $p:\mathbb{R}^{d}\rightarrow\mathbb{T}^{d}$
  the canonical projection of the real d- dimensional space in to the d-dimensional torus, and suppose to have a diffeomorphism (or more in genearl an homeomorphism) $\varphi:\mathbb{T}^{d}\longrightarrow\mathbb{T}^{d}$
  that i can lift to a diffeomorphism $\tilde{\varphi}:\mathbb{R}^{d}\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}^{d}$
  such that $p\circ\tilde{\varphi}=\varphi\circ p$
 . It's true that i can write like $\tilde{\varphi}\left(x\right)=Ax+u\left(x\right)$
  where $A\in Sl(\mathbb{Z},d)$
  and $u\left(x\right)$
 is periodic ?

I have proved that if A
  is a lift of a linear diffeomorphism of the torus than it lies in $Sl(\mathbb{Z},d)$.
  Any suggestion for the rest?

Comment: A will have to be in $GL(\mathbb Z,d)$.

Comment: Yes, but because it's invertible and its inverse is the lift of the inverse, it lies in $Gl(Z,d)$ too. So its determinat must be +/-1 , right ?

Comment: But $SL(d,\mathbb Z)$ is the group of matrices of determinant equal to $1$, not $\pm1$.

Comment: Why do you need $A$ in the form for $\tilde \varphi$? It's simply true that any lift will be periodic. And of course, transforming such a lift by an element of $GL(d, \mathbb Z)$ will give an equivalent lift. But those are two independent statements. Now, if you demanded that the range of $\tilde \varphi$ should lie in $[0,1]^d$ that would be something else...

Comment: Ok, you are right my fault... take it in $(+/-)Sl(Z,d)$.

Comment: I need the A for a following statement. I know that the lift is periodic, I'm sorry but I do not uderstand what you mean with trasform the lift by an element of $Gl(Z,d)$(by Traslation?) and what you mean with the range of the lift... The lift goes from $R^d$ to itself

Comment: @user52342, what you write $(+/-)SL(\mathbb Z,d)$ is precisely what the standard notation $GL(\mathbb Z,d)$ stands for...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a continuous $\varphi \colon \mathbb{T}^d \to \mathbb{T}^d$ and a lift $\tilde{\varphi} \colon \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}^d$ of $\varphi$, then for every $z \in \mathbb{Z}^d$, the function $\psi_z\colon \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}^d; \: \psi_z(x) = \tilde{\varphi}(x+z) - \tilde{\varphi}(x)$ is continuous and $\mathbb{Z}^d$- valued, since $$p(\tilde{\varphi}(x+z)) = \varphi(p(x+z)) = \varphi(p(x)) = p(\tilde{\varphi}(x)),$$ hence constant. It is easy to see that $z \mapsto \psi_z(0) = \tilde{\varphi}(z) - \tilde{\varphi}(0)$ is $\mathbb{Z}$-linear, so we can write $\psi_z(0) = Az$ with a matrix $A \in M_d(\mathbb{Z})$. Then $u \colon \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}^d;\; u(x) = \tilde{\varphi}(x) - Ax$ is $\mathbb{Z}^d$-periodic, since

$$u(x+z) = \tilde{\varphi}(x+z) - A(x+z) = \tilde{\varphi}(x) + \psi_z(x) - Ax - Az = u(x) + \bigl(\psi_z(x) - Az\bigr) = u(x).$$

If $\varphi$ is a homeomorphism, then $\tilde{\varphi}\bigl([0,1)^d\bigr)$ is a fundamental region of the lattice $\mathbb{Z}^d$, hence then $A \in GL_d(\mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: Is the A a lift of a linear homeomorphism ? For this he as to stay in $Gl(Z,d)$?

Comment: $A$, or rather $x \mapsto Ax$ is the lift of a linear homeomorphism if and only if $A \in GL_d(\mathbb{Z})$. Thus in this construction, where you got $A$ from the lift of a homeomorphism, it is. And $u$ pushes down to a perturbation of the linear homeomorphism.

Comment: sorry but i cant see the linear Homeomorphism of the torus of which A is the lift...

Comment: $p\circ A$ is $\mathbb{Z}^d$-periodic, so $A$ induces $\alpha \colon \mathbb{T}^d \to \mathbb{T}^d$. $A^{-1}$ induces $\alpha^{-1}$, so $\alpha$ is a bijection of the torus.

Comment: but how you define $A^-1$ ? thank you....

Comment: $A\in GL_d(\mathbb{Z})$, that means it has an inverse in $GL_d(\mathbb{Z})$. That inverse induces the inverse mapping up in $\mathbb{R}^d$, and that pushes down to $\mathbb{T}^d$.

Comment: I'm sorry again... i think i'm not understanding you ... I have to proves that $A∈GL_d(Z)$ since A is the lift of a linear homeomorphism so i cant use the fact that that is has an inverse because $A∈GL_d(Z)$ ... $ A^−1 $ is not defined since you proves that $A∈GL_d(Z)$...

Comment: Last line in the answer, if $\varphi$ is a homeomorphism, the corresponding matrix $A$ is in $GL_d(\mathbb{Z})$, because $\tilde{\varphi}([0,1)^d)$ is a fundamental region of the lattice. If $\varphi$ is a linear homeomorphism of the tori, the corresponding $u$ is constant, so $\tilde{\varphi}$ is the composition of a translation (by a lattice point) and a linear isomorphism induced by an $A\in GL_d(\mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: Ok thank you i have only one more question ... can you explain to me why because $φ~([0,1)^d)$ is a fundamental region $A$ have to be in $GL_d(Z)$?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10806/discussion-between-user52342-and-daniel-fischer)

Comment: Ok i have done thank you ...